# Issue of running laravel previous version on laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

I am having some problem running Laravel 4 project on my environment.
My development environment:

```
MacOS High Sierra
Laravel 5.6
PHP 7.1.14
Homebrew 1.6.4
XAMPP 7.1.16
Composer version 1.6.2
```

When I try to do

```
php artisan serve
```

It shows me error message:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I checked that Mcrypt is already deprecated by the community, and I saw a lot of solution for install Mcrypt on php 7.1, but it all doesn't work out for me. I am thinking about just upgrade entire project laravel 4 to laravel 5.6 manually. Do you guys have any recommendation for case, either the manually upgrade or solve the dependency problem?

Comment: You'll either need to run on PHP 5 or upgrade Laravel to v5. Upgrading Laravel would be my choice - PHP 5 will eventually be deprecated, and 7 comes with lots of improvements (as does Laravel 5). Potentially lots of work, but worthwhile. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade to get started. You'll have to upgrade to 5.0, then to 5.1, and so on.

Comment: @ceejayoz From that link it says "The recommended method of upgrading is to create a new Laravel 5.0 install and then to copy your 4.2 site's unique application files into the new application." So wouldn't it be better just to create a new 5.6 install and copy the unique application files over instead of upgrading in stages like you mentioned?

Comment: @Mike If you prefer, go for it. You'll still have to make all the changes in the upgrade path from v4 to v5.6, though, so you'll essentially wind up following a similar procedure.

Comment: I probably just upgraded from 4.2 to 5.0 first, and then upgraded it to 5.6, and I also heard there is https://laravelshift.com/, which is the tool to help laravel project upgrade. Is it legit? @ceejayoz

Comment: We used it once. Was fairly good, but there'll be a lot of things it flags that you still have to fix manually.